# Use Typescript Class without declare a object

Tags: typescript

someone knows how to use a typescript class without declare a object, on php is someting like `MyClass::AnyFunction()` or `MyClass::attribute`.

I can do it using `(new MyClass()).MyFunctionOrAttribute`, but i don't know if there is another way, yeah my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [static methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties) which TypeScript supports:

```
class MyClass {
  static AnyFunction() {

  }
}

MyClass.AnyFunction(); // Works
```

Comment: Good but there is any way to use "this" value inside static functions?

Comment: You can use `this` but it will reference the current class instead of the instance.